# how to send email in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

how to send email in iphone SDK? any example tutorial to take email address from iphone
also?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application

Comment: A duplicate yes, but the question is old and only have iPhone OS 2.0 answers.

Comment: Try using search before asking questions. It'll help a lot if you vote up already posted correct answers.

Comment: Actually, an answer on that question does talk about MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone OS 3.0, so it covers this topic well.

Answer (score 17):

You should use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class, and the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol, that that tucked away in the MessageUI framework.

First to send a message:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Then the user does the work and you get the delegate callback in time:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error;
{
  if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
    NSLog(@"It's away!");
  }
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```