# iphone app userid

Tags: iphone, email, email-validation, userid

I have an app where we want users to be able to send us email/info. This would be a standard template which will open up on a button click within the app.

I am struggling at the moment to find a legit way to do it. The problem is there are 2 things I need.

1) A way to let users send email to me
2) A way of knowing the person sending me mail is actually someone who has downloaded my app.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? Does apple give us information/user id's or email id's of poeple who have downloaded the app?

Many thanks in advance for any help with this..

PB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application/1258277#1258277) a good example on how to send email.
As for identifying if they send it from your app, you might have to create some login feature on your own. I haven't heard of Apple providing IDs of users who have bought your app.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the quick answer, it helps for #1 .
My next problem is how to identify uniquely the person sending this to me. I would not want the same person to send the mail to me twice with two different id's. If I create a login, can I restrict one user to have only one login id? Can someone not create multiple logins especially if there is no way to track them back to their apple id's?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You could use email addresses, so they would have to register more than one email address to register more than once with you. Or you could use a service like OpenFeint that does all the registering of names, etc for you. From what I have seen, this is the best you can do. Unless someone wants to prove me otherwise (which I wouldn't mind) Apple doesn't allow you to access the information you need.