# mail sqlite values in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, email

I'm creating an app that has a database using sqlite. On my app I've populated a UITableView with the data from the sqlite database. The values on the tableView can be edit by user and save it on the sqilte.
What I wanted to do was I need to mail the values from that table. How can I insert the values of that table to the mail that my app will compose or could I take a screen shot of that table the attach it to the mail?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is just a matter of sending an email within your app. To accomplish follow the guidelines in this thread: [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

If you want to send the values from the table just put them in the body of the email.