# How can I make a call inside an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tel

I want the user to make a call from my application

Something like this post, but instead of sending an email, make a call
[How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Tanks!

Comment: Removed cocoa and mac tags as this has nothing to do with either of those areas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE: This will only work on an actual iPhone (not the simulator)**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:9995551234"]];
```

Comment: It will do nothing if you are in the simulator, but it works

Comment: @caeycae:  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  Glad it worked out for you.