# MFMailComposeViewController send the email!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

So I am trying to send an in application email on the iPad using the MFMailComposeViewController.   However, everything I am reading shows how to set it up and get it ready, but not how to actually send it!  I have the delegate all set up and handling the button clicks, but am not sure how to say "Now go send the email".  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: duplicate question found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your delegate methods are set up correctly, you present the `MFMailComposeViewController` modally and the view controller handles the sending itself. and calls the protocol method `mailComposeController: didFinishWithResult: error:` when the user finishes with the modal view controller.

Comment: Right, but how do you actually SEND the email.  Or is that automatic?  I have that didFinishWithResult: method set up and a switch statement that handles the different cases, but it's not SENDING.

Comment: Nevermind, it does, but the email is not actually going out.  Any idea why?  Do I need to set a sender or anything?

Comment: Are you running on the simulator? You wont be able to actually send the email till you get this onto your hardware which will (probably) have a real email setup. The sim version just vanishes into nowhere.

Comment: the view controller does not handle the actual SENDING of the email, it sends the email to the email queue on the device and then that deals with sending it when it can (has internet/etc)

Comment: Ah gotya that's the problem.  It is indeed on the simulator.  Thanks!