# Returning to app after sending to mail client

Tags: iphone, email, safari, hyperlink

The jamie oliver application and the nigella quick collection apps both return the user to the application after they've sent a feedback email.

My question is, how do I return a user to the app after sending them to the email client. Plus, is there any way to do this with the safari app too? After sending them to a URL?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Jamie Oliver app but I believe he is using the `MFMailComposeViewController`. If you want more info on how to send an email from within an app, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application).