# batch scan qr codes that contain an email address and message and auto send the emails once scanned

Tags: iphone, qr-code, mass-emails

I want to do a logistics project that entails scanning alot of qr codes(500) all of which contain a unique email address and message.  I've seen scanner apps that will batch scan them but in order to send the messages they must be opened first and then you have to press the send button.  I want to send all the messages or else I wouldn't have scanned their qr code.  Any idea of a scanner app that will auto send the emails immediately upon scanning the code?
I'm using an iphone for scanning and sending the emails

thanks for taking the time to help!

Lance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I send email programmatically in iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119522/can-i-send-email-programmatically-in-iphone-app)

Comment: If you're looking for an existing app, then you're asking in the wrong place. You might try [superuser](http://superuser.com/) instead. If that's the case, flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it for you -- that's better than cross posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send e-mail without user interaction using the email API provided by Apple in iOS. Two ways to do it are:

1. Build your own SMTP client into your app, so that you can connect directly to a SMTP server and send messages.
2. Construct a web service to which you can send e-mail messages, or perhaps just the information required to construct and send the messages. Have your app send the messages via this web service.