# iOS Email Field Data directly to email without opening Apple Mail

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

In my app, my user fills out first name and email fields. I want to send this data to an email address when the user taps the "Submit" button, but the only way I can seem to do that is by having the Apple Mail client open. Right now, I'm using the following code - is there a way to send field data to a specific email address without launching Apple Mail? **E.g.** user taps "submit", and gets pushed to a "Thank You" view?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail =[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *emailbody = email.text;
NSString *firstnamebody = firstName.text;

[mail setMessageBody:emailbody isHTML:NO];
[mail setMessageBody:firstnamebody isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: Do you want the email sent from the user's email address or can it be from yours?

Comment: @rmaddy Preferably from the user's email address (pulled from the email field).

Comment: Then it can't be done. You need to use `MFMailComposeViewController` (or launch the Mail app) to have the email be sent from the user's email address.

Comment: @rmaddy Lame - haha. What if I'm fine with it coming from my own specified email address?

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427056/how-to-send-mail-from-iphone-app-without-showing-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: It's not lame. It's to prevent a 3rd party app from sending SPAM from user's devices under their email address. It's a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you send the data to some server and the server sends the email for you. This could be your server or a 3rd party service you use (via a REST interface probably).