# How to work with Email in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, email

Please tell me how to send an email?

That means i have an uibutton when the user clicks that i want retrieve some data from app and send it to technical assistant`s mail id.. is there any simple method for doing this?

Comment: Please stop to tag your questions with xcode just because you are using this IDE to create your app. The Xcode tag should be used for questions regarding Xcode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to create UIButton.  You have to use the MFMailComposeViewController class and the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol to send a mail..

For your easiness in creating e-mail app your can refer to the following link.

http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/

it may be helpful to you in creating your app

Answer (score 11):

You have to use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class, and the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol,

PeyloW provides the following code for this in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application/1513433#1513433):

> First to send a message:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

> Then the user does the work and you
>   get the delegate callback in time:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error;
{
  if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
    NSLog(@"It's away!");
  }
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated - is Depricated please Use    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send an email from your users email account you need to use the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendingaMailMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010415-SW1) to present the user with a screen. You can't/shouldn't send emails from the users email account without their permission!

Otherwise you can start a normal SMTP connection to your server and use your own login details.

Answer (score 2):

I use the simple method of composing an email and opening it with the Mail app. This also works as a confirmation; if the user doesn't want to send it, he can just cancel. So no need to add an 'Are you sure?' popup. He can also add a note or such.

```
    NSString *mailurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"mailto:%@?subject=%@%@&body=%@%@",mailaddr,mailsubject,
recipientname,mailmessage,mailsignature];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
[NSURL URLwithString:[mailurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

It works a charm and I use this method in several apps :)