# Email app from another app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to start an email app from app on button pressed. But when I pressed the button nothing is happening !!!

code :

```
- (IBAction) startMail
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:emailAdress?subject=testMail&body=its test mail."]];
}
```

any thing wrong in code ? Also button is properly set in IB.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compose an EMail inside your app, you should have a look at the [MFMailComposeViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to do so instead of calling a mailto: URL scheme.

Comment: how can I set the " to " field ? as data comes from previous view's table. and setToRecipients method requires the NSArray ! I have only one record (email address).

Comment: use `[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourEmailAddressString]` to create your array

Comment: done ... thanks.. one more thing can I access the msg body ? I mean if I use setMessageBody to display default text and when I click on the body all default text should be cleared .. any idea ?

Comment: This is not a supported behavior I guess.

Comment: and second thing when I click on saveDraft button then app gets crashed... how to handle it ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the mailto URL won't work in the simulator as mail.app isn't installed on the simulator. It does work on device though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "MFMailComposeViewController" to send mail from your application.

Sample code-

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker;

picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *objSubject = [[NSString alloc] init];<br/>
NSString *emailBody = [[NSString alloc] init];
[picker setSubject:objSubject];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

You must use the following delegate to check the status of mail sent or not

```
**-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
}**
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",
                        [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [body  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
```

Here to, subject and body are NSString variables

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it's a better solution than directing your user out of the app;
[How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:foo@example.com?cc=bar@example.com&subject=Greetings%20from%20Cupertino!&body=Wish%20you%20were%20here!"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```