# i want to open from my aap. "settings >> mail >> add account " (the add account page) is it possible.?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app, if the user has not configured their E-mail account on their iPhone, then when the user opens the application, it will ask for e-mail configuration (means the app redirects to  "settings  >> mail >>  add account " add account page),

How can I do that?

I searched and found one similar question in stack overflow but it was not helpful.
[just like this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015855/how-do-i-show-the-mail-setup-page-programatically-in-iphone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i show the mail setup page programatically in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015855/how-do-i-show-the-mail-setup-page-programatically-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

just see the official sample code.Here is the link:[SampleCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

find the launchMailAppOnDevice() function.

```
// Launches the Mail application on the device.
-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello from California!";
    NSString *body = @"&body=It is raining in sunny California!";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

It was useful for me. Hope it can help you.