# Mail - Add Account screen from UIActivityController

Tags: swift, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

I implemented a simple `UIActivityViewController` as below

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError in
    if let error = activityError where !completed && activityType != nil {
        // report the error
    }
}
```

I thought the `Add Account` screen for Mail could be handled automatically by the `UIActivityViewController` instance if the user have no mail accounts, but not, it's not doing it.

The first thing I tried was to analyze the completion closure: the `activityError` instance is nil and the `completed` value is `false`. Great, I put this workaround ([i want to open from my aap. "settings >> mail >> add account " (the add account page) is it possible.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689152/i-want-to-open-from-my-aap-settings-mail-add-account-the-add-account)) whenever this closure with those values is called. But it's called also when the user press `Cancel` on the mail composer.

So, how do Photos and other not-Apple apps they handle this scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Apple doesn't handle well a `NSURL` type in the activityItems. 
I solved it by using `absoluteString` value of that instance.