# Sending an email automatically through my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, email, xcode4

I am new to iPhone app development. I have a form that the user can fill out to request additional information about my product. I would like the app to automatically send out the email without launching UI.

I have looked through several posts that have recommended using `ASIHTTPRequest` to "Post" data. However most of the posts are dated back to 2009. My question is that using Xcode 4 is there another way of accomplishing the same thing without using `ASIHTTPRequest`?

Thanks
T!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application

Comment: Please don't try to destroy good user experience of iOS.

Comment: I would suggest that you just use the standard controls. It's better.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send emails without the standard mail composer you have to

1. ask the user for his email address
2. implement [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP). And SMTP is more complex than a simple POST to http.

Alternatively you could set up a script on a web server to which you send the mail address you got from the user.