# How to take a picture and send it as an email attachment in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera, attachment

Currently, I can set a button to take a picture, but I'm unsure how to pass this as an attachment for an email in the same view.
The view is for a quote and allows the user to enter data into a few fields then has a button to email said data.

Comment: [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this link would satisfy your requirement for the second half of the question...

http://www.ericd.net/2009/04/sending-email-from-iphone-application.html

```
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mobiletuts-logo.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png"   fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"];
```

Courtesy:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/

Comment: Thanks for the help...but I'm trying to 'push' the file from the camera as an attachment without having to save it first.

Comment: You can save it to library and access photo from there..Its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's MailComposer example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865