# How to send mail without showing the mail composer view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, email

I am developing an iPhone application in which I have to send mail to only recipient without showing the MFMailComposer UI view (i.e without user interaction). Can please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot send Email without user acceptance. But there are a lot of web-services in internet which can send Email. I guess some app uses those services or uses own.

See also [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Comment: the link you have given is not the answer what rinku yadav asked.
Even i was looking for the same but when i click on your given link.. it was useless to (rinku yadav) question..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the gmail mail facilities into the xcode

For that following to gives much more tutorial and source code here

[Reference link](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/13/sending-a-mail-useing-gmail/)

Comment: hello samuel i have try your code but it always give me Unable to send message can you please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Using openURL method of UIApplication, you can send the mail without using mail composer. For that you should select "mailto" option.