# How to send a mail without disclosing recipients mail id in ios

Tags: ios

All I am developing an iPhone application in which I have to send mail to recipient without showing email id and the MFMailComposer UI view (i.e without user interaction and also user cant know who is the recipient). Can please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send Email without user acceptance. But there are a lot of web-services in internet which can send Email. I guess some app uses those services or uses own.

See also [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP webpage which uses the mail function, just a couple of lines of code.
Then just call the url to that php webpage from your app!