# I can't open Mail app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, openurl

I'm trying to open iOS's mail application by clicking a button.

So I did this :

```
NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto://test@test.com"];   
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
```

But nothing in particular happens... what's the problem ?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Here is a very good explanation for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application/1513433#1513433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@"mailto:test@test.com"
```

instead of

```
@"mailto://test@test.com"
```

Better way of doing this would be to use [MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513433/251012)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just realized that I don't have Mail app in my Simulator... is it normal ?

Comment: @RobinDreux, yes, that is normal. Also, you shouldn't use stringWithFormat unless you are actually using a format string. I would imagine that your compiler is giving you a warning.

Answer (score 0):

And it works only on the real device, not on the simulator (in my case)