# Is it possible to download and upload documents on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to download documents (e.g. DOC, PDF, etc.), and sends documents by email on iPhone and iPad? For example, we can download images using the browser and send images by email.

Answer (score 1):

You can [associate a file type](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/04/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application.aspx) for your app (so your app can open an attachment with corresponding extension), and you can [send mail programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application) with the appropriate attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for uploading and downloading files. Read the "How To Get Started" section in the tutorial.