# How to programmatically open SMS and email options one after another in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, sms

I am developing a mobile app where I want to open email just after SMS is sent to the selected user. I am developing it something like the one done in MessageMe app in iOS where when a user clicks on Invite, he is asked to select the recipients. If he selects two people from contact which have one phone number and other have an email selected, as soon as he clicks on send, the SMS view open and he clicks on send sms. Soon after SMS is sent, another window opens which shows send mail option and thus a user simultaneously sends email as well as SMS to different users.

Please input your response with the coding on how to do that.

Comment: Please put your code and let us see what you tried and where is issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{

 // open sms view controller
}
```

you can try this.

Comment: Hi Hitendra, I already tried this but nothing happens or changes.

Answer (score 0):

Below url contains good tutorial for SMS
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/ 
Now once you get success response from message you can use MFMailComposer to send mail by using help from below url:
[How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Tried the same including other ways also, but when I click on Invite, the app crashes sometimes and sometime it works. Don't know why does this happens.