# Html File In Messages App Not Viewing correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have code that is generating an HTML file that is being sent via iMessage to another iPhone user. However, in the messages App on the receiving end, when they click on the HTML file, the formatting is super bare. (I know the HTML file works, because I forward it to a computer and it displays fine) There's none of the images displayed on the HTML file when viewed in the Messages App, and I have a Youtube video embedded that is not being displayed. My best guess is that the Messages app is stripping away all of this information... So how could I go about displaying my HTML file correctly? Could I somehow force it to open in Safari? I tried converting the HTML file to a PDF with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Are you serious? This is the first time I heard someone sent a HTML with images and video through a SMS. Shouldn't you send it to the user's email?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Not possible. iMessage sends text messages as SMS, images or videos as MMS, which may incur extra cost to your user if they are not on WIFI. Never seen a HTML being sent with image and video before.

You can send the HTML file via email. And if you provide a link in your email, the Mail app will open it in Safari automatically.

There are many answers on sending mail from iPhone apps: [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've already implemented the ability to send via email, but also wanted to let them send via SMS. It's not text, but an attached HTML file via SMS. Most of the HTML loads fine when it's clicked on in iMessage, but just the images and video are stripped out. Any ideas?

Comment: The basic of SMS is text-only and limited to 160 characters only. You can google on "SMS" and see how it works.

Comment: Hi, it's not actually an SMS message, but an attachment. Here's a screenshot: <img>http://i57.tinypic.com/152jh49.jpg</img>

Comment: It doesn't matter. SMS is text-only. No image, no video, no attachment. Only 160 characters.

Comment: I guess it's not SMS I'm talking about then— just using iMessage to send the attached HTML file to other iPhone users. I have no problem sending and receiving the HTML file, but it's just that some of the formatting is stripped out (only pictures and videos).

Comment: Ok, I have to correct myself too. You can use iMessage to send text-only message, photos and videos SEPARATELY. However, depending on the user's data plan, it might incur extra cost to them if they are not on wifi.