# What is the right way to keep notes file in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have a .swift file with notes about what to do in the project:

```
/*
v1.1: do this
v1.1.1: update this
v1.3: optimize this
*/
```

Its over 100 lines long and I think that there might be a better way to hold these types of notes. Does this in anyway reduce my compiling time or affect my project?

Comment: I usually just have a file called `TO_DO.txt` in the project.

Comment: The problem is txt file doesn't look good on xcode and I have lines like this: -Add mail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application

In commented code this is a clickable URL. In txt it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `todo.swift` file for these kinds of notes. `.swift` file allows links to be clickable also enables colorings. Other formats like `txt` doesn't allow these.