# Send UITextView to Email (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, email

I have created an area in my application where users are able to report bugs and other issues. Is there a way for me to have the "send" button send the text in the UITextView to my email address?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send email with `MFMailComposer`.

But if you plan to send email without `MFMailComposer` or user acceptance, you cannot. But there are a lot of web-services in internet which can send Email. I guess some app uses those services or uses own.

This might be helpful [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)