# Want to send custom emails i.e. Welcome mail from firebase using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, email, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase as my backend in one of my project. I want to send an email to the recipient whenever he is added into the group. Below is the structure of my DB.

```
Main Group
-----Root
       -----Users
               ---- Friend-1
               ---- Friend-2
        .
        .
        and so on
```

What I want is to trigger an email whenever a new friend is added in the group Users. I searched and found 3 types of emails supported by firebase but that is only for the main users which are seen in Authentication tab on console.

Answer (score 2):

You can either send email directly from the phone, as described here: [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Alternatively, you can send email from the Firebase servers by using Cloud Functions for Firebase. Your use-case is closest to the [Send confirmation emails to users subscribing/unsubscribing to a newsletter.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#other_interesting_notification_use_cases) sample in the list of use-cases.